# Check kbps and resolution video before upload it to server

Tags: video, kaltura, videoquality

I would like to know if there is a way to check kbps and resolution before upload it to server.

Note: We are using kaltura service.

Comment: Quality is a subject if metric. We can only measure something if we can define it. What do you take to being quality as pertaining to this question?

Comment: I mean kbps and resolution sorry

Answer (score 0):

https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo can tell you the file metadata including resolution and kbps